# Limpar notificações antigas no momento que entrar no aplicativo

Tags: android, android-notification

Alguém sabe como faço para limpar as notificações antigas do meu aplicativo a partir do momento que eu entro no app através do Ícone e não da própria notificação. O Whatsapp faz isso no android, mas não conseguir encontrar uma maneira de trabalhar com isso, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar isso no onCreate da sua UI Thread:

```
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

O sistema vai buscar todas as notificações ativas e limpá-las.

Comment: Vlw, deu certo!